# Can we send data to partials in ejs?

Tags: javascript, ejs

**Objective : **
I need to send text into patials in ejs.
Say i need to change the title of webpage for different webpage.Since i have refactored the common code and placed into an seperate file. Can i pass data to it

**Code**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Home</title>
</head>
```

Say I need to change the title of the partial for different pages.

Answer (score 0):

If you place the partial for example **head.ejs** in your code, the data sent to this code will also be sent to **head.ejs**.

For example if you send the value title to your index.js code, you can put this in your head partial.

[image]

Comment: But how do u specify the object in head partial 
Ex: <%- include('header') -%> here how do u specify the object to send?

Comment: The same way you specify how to send it to the main ejs file where the partials is included in. Ejs puts all the partials in to the main code as it would all be the same code.

Comment: Could you share the code ? on how you will be passing